# Running NextJS on production azure app service?

Tags: reactjs, azure, next.js

I have a nextjs react website running fine locally, after I ran 'next build' I got a .next file. I tried uploading the contents to azure app services but when I visit the URL I get an error that I don't have permission to view this page.

From googling the issue I've found that I need to install something on the azure app service: https://github.com/MRCollective/nextjs-server-azuresiteextension - "Install the nextjs-server site extension (either via the Portal or programmatically via ARM)" but I don't understand what that means or where I can find it (extensions in portal and site extensions does not have nextjs-server)

Comment: Is running it as a docker container an option for you?

Comment: I'm willing to try it and see

Comment: I'm also looking proper solution to deploy nextjs react website on azure app services.

Comment: Do you need to it be hosted as static html or something else with Azure App Services?

Comment: @technogeek1995 No unfortunately it's not a static site.

Comment: Looks like it's not in the portal due to issues (see [todos](https://github.com/MRCollective/nextjs-server-azuresiteextension#todo))

Comment: Are you using express? Can you get express to proxy requests to Next? Or are you doing SSR with Next? Can you add some more information about what you want the `azure-app-service` to do?

Comment: Any luck on this? Can't believe there's no proper info on how to get a Next app inside an Azure App Service...

Comment: @emzero have posted an answer

Comment: @meds have you managed to find any solution to this?